# Which are the use of other index.html in a PhoneGap app?

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

After I created a PhoneGap and add two platforms:

```
$ cordova create test com.example.test Test
$ cd test
$ cordova platform add ios
$ cordova platform add android    
$ cordova platform list 
Installed platforms: android 3.5.0, ios 3.5.0
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, blackberry10, firefoxos
```

There are 3 `index.html` files:

```
$ find . -name index.html 
./platforms/android/assets/www/index.html
./platforms/ios/www/index.html
./www/index.html
```

The `./www/index.html` is loaded when running iOS simulator:

```
cordova emulate ios
```

What are the use of:

```
./platforms/android/assets/www/index.html
./platforms/ios/www/index.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The www/index.html is copied to the other platforms on a `cordova build <platform>`.
The copying actually takes places on `cordova prepare <platform>`

Note: you can also create a index.html in merges/ios/index.html where you can differentiate between a file for different platforms. of course this also works with other files then index.html.

Answer (score 1):

From the official Cordova documentation

> Running commands to add or remove platforms affects the contents of
>   the project's `platforms` directory, where each specified platform
>   appears as a subdirectory. The `www` source directory is reproduced
>   within each platform's subdirectory, appearing for example in
>   `platforms/ios/www` or `platforms/android/assets/www`. Because the CLI
>   constantly copies over files from the source `www` folder, you should
>   only edit these files and not the ones located under the platforms
>   subdirectories. If you use version control software, you should add
>   this source `www` folder, along with the `merges` folder, to your version
>   control system. (More information about the merges folder can be found
>   in the Customize Each Platform section below.)
>
> **WARNING**: When using the CLI to build your application, you should not
>   edit any files in the `/platforms/` directory unless you know what you
>   are doing, or if documentation specifies otherwise. The files in this
>   directory are routinely overwritten when preparing applications for
>   building, or when plugins are reinstalled.
>
> If you wish at this point, you can use an SDK such as Eclipse or Xcode
>   to open the project you created. You will need to open the derivative
>   set of assets from the `/platforms/` directory to develop with an SDK.
>   This is because the SDK specific metadata files are stored within the
>   appropriate `/platform/` subdirectory. (See the Platform Guides for
>   information on how to develop applications within each IDE.) Use this
>   approach if you simply want to initialize a project using the CLI and
>   then switch to an SDK for native work.

Original link:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0//guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface_add_platforms

Answer (score 0):

The ./www/index.html gets copied to the various platforms on a build / run.